# GROUP BY in SSMS vs MySql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql-server, group-by, ssms, aggregate-functions

**Question :** Write a query that obtains two columns. The first column must contain annual salaries higher than 80,000 dollars. The second column, renamed to “emps_with_same_salary”, must show the number of employees contracted to that salary. Lastly, sort the output by the first column. Need output in SSMS.

**Sol:**

Please note, this solution below gives the output in MySql Workbench but not in SSMS.

select salary, count(emp_no) as emps_with_same_salary
from salaries
where salary > '80000'
group by emp_no;

**OUTPUT:**

salary      emps_with_same_salary

'80001'       , '7'

'80007'        , '11'

'80056'        , '5'

Comment: Somehow I doubt your query works correctly in any database engine. The count should be the number of employees with a particular salary (e.g., 80001), Grouping by emp_no makes no logical sense because the count in your resultset should be 1 (if we assume that your table has one row per emp_no) for every single row. You will get one row per unique value of emp_no if you group on that column. You should be grouping on salary. And lastly, your resultset has no defined order since it has no order by clause. Do not assume based on observation.

Answer (score -1):

This is the query you should be using in SQL Server. It will likely work in MySQL as well but I do not know that particular SQL dialect.

```
select salary, count(emp_no) as emps_with_same_salary
from dbo.salaries 
where salary > 80000 
group by salary
order by salary;
```

Notice that I removed the single quotes around your constant in the WHERE clause. You don't (and shouldn't) enclose numeric constants in single quotes. This implies to the reader that your column is string when it usually is not. If your column is varchar (or similar), then you have a very different set of issues to address (since a salary of '9' > '80000'). Also notice the use of a schema-qualified table name - a best practice.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The problem with that is, its giving the output but not as desired. If you see the output that I have shown in the question (also shown below). I was expecting this output). When I run the query that you gave, it gives 1 for count(emp_no).

OUTPUT:

salary emps_with_same_salary

'80001' , '7'

'80007' , '11'

'80056' , '5'

Comment: "not desired" is not a useful comment - especially when you proved no sample data. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4fd5cda50a73c9e3f0fd231f6617198e) to demonstrate my understanding of your goal.